# Issue for Group By in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

Now the below code is grouped by employeeid

```
select   
    COUNT(employeelog.employeeid) as empVisit,  
    employeelog.employeeid as employeeID
into 
    #tempdr
from 
    Filteredps_employeelog as employeelog 
where 
    employeelog.ps_employeetypename in (@employeevisit, @empfamvisit)
group by   
    employeelog.employeeid
```

I want to group by `admissionid`. When I tried as below expected result is not returned. Is this the right way to group by admissionid?

```
select  
    COUNT(employeelog.admissionid) as empadmission
into 
    #tempdr
from 
    Filteredps_employeelog as employeelog 
where 
    employeelog.ps_employeetypename in (@employeevisit, @empfamvisit)
group by   
    employeelog.admissionid
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the purpose of your second query , so it will be little clear to give an answer..

Comment: I want to groupby admissionid for getting the real number of employeevisit

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql server is the one

Answer (score 0):

so, you need to get number of employees with same admissionid right?

change your query like this..

```
select employeelog.admissionid,COUNT(employeelog.employeeid) as empadmission
          into #tempdr
          from Filteredps_employeelog as  employeelog 
          where employeelog.ps_employeetypename in(@employeevisit ,@empfamvisit)
       group by   employeelog.admissionid,employeelog.employeeid
```

**EDIT:**

try this one if you just want the admissionid count for each

```
select employeelog.admissionid,COUNT(employeelog.admissionid) as empadmission
      into #tempdr
      from Filteredps_employeelog as  employeelog 
      where employeelog.ps_employeetypename in(@employeevisit ,@empfamvisit)
   group by   employeelog.admissionid
```

Comment: Line 130
Column 'Filteredps_employeelog ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. error is showing . please note,I want count(admissionid) and groupby admissionid.Thanks